# 2 threads in a class have to perform different actions. My code is not working

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a form. On button click, it should redirect to a dll wherein there are 2 classes.
Classxyz:
Has 2 threads.
Thread 1: should have the method that inserts a string into an array
Thread 2: should have the method that returns the first element from the array
Classarray:
The array is in a classarray.

My problem:
I am not able to understand if my threads are performing their tasks.

Class xyz:

```
        public void ToDo(string str)
       {
        ThreadObject firstThreadObject = new ThreadObject();
        firstThreadObject.str = str;


        Thread firstThread = new Thread(DoWorkpeek);
        firstThread.Start(firstThreadObject);


        ThreadObject secondThreadObject = new ThreadObject();

        secondThreadObject.str = str;
        Thread secondThread = new Thread(DoWorkenque);
        secondThread.Start(secondThreadObject);

        firstThread.Abort();
        secondThread.Abort();

    }

    public void DoWorkpeek(object parameter)
    {
        ThreadObject threadObject = parameter as ThreadObject;
        str1 = objq.queuepeek(threadObject.str);
        MessageBox.Show(str1);
    }
    public void DoWorkenque(object parameter)
    {
        ThreadObject threadObject = parameter as ThreadObject;
        objq.enqueue(threadObject.str);
    }
```

Is my code correct?

```
MessageBox.show(str1);
```

is not showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `Join()` the threads, don't `Abort()` them.

Second, you could use a `ParameterizedThreadStart` object to start the threads, like so:

```
Thread firstThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoWorkpeek));
firstThread.Start(str);

...

firstThread.Join();
secondThread.Join();
```

Also, make sure that your objq object is accessible by both threads (e.g. is static) and lock it when accessing, like so:

```
ThreadObject threadObject = parameter as ThreadObject;
lock(objq)
    str1 = objq.queuepeek(threadObject.str);
MessageBox.Show(str1);
```

Also, instead of using `MessageBox.Show(str1)`, you could use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(str1)` and write to the Debug output window.

Comment: Thank You. I got the output in the Debug window. Since the messageBox was not working I wasnt sure if the control reached that part of code and is working properly. Could you please explain why it is better to Join() and not abort(). I am new to coding in threading.

Comment: And, Will parameters only be cosidered if parameterizedThreadStart is used?

Comment: Well, Abort() terminates the thread and might interrupt its execution. Join() waits for the thread to finish to continue execution. Check out these links to see details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b50fdsz.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx.

Comment: ParameterizedThreadStart is the usual way one would pass parameters to a thread.